# TLFX, has anybody used it yet?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex4, tlf

Has anybody use TLFX yet?

The repository is here: http://code.google.com/p/tlfx/ but I'm not sure it's completed. I tried to compile it but look like some classes are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a brief look in to it but then got sidetracked with looking in to [TinyTLF](http://github.com/guyinthechair/tinytlf) ( Which is really awesome )

Comment: Oh and some classes were missing for me too.

Comment: TinyTLF looks great, but I need the editing functionality. tks.